# Why does my Xubuntu 16.04 desktop think that it is a laptop? How do I instruct it otherwise?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display, laptop

I have a desktop and it has a single screen attached to it. It appears that something in my hardware is causing various flavors of Ubuntu to identify my device as a laptop with an additional screen. As a result (I think) Ubuntu 16.04 was completely useless; all the time I would lose my mouse to the screen that did not exist. Xubuntu 16.04 is serviceable, but there are oddities still in the behavior.

Attached is a link to a screenshot obtained by going to *Settings > Displays > Identify Displays*. It appears to show a laptop display superimposed on my real screen. In fact, I only have the BenQ 1920*1280 display.

What can I do to identify the cause of the problem? The command `sudo lshw` provides lots of information starting with "description: Desktop Computer", which is correct. The command `sudo laptop-detect -v` returns the response "We're not on a laptop (no relevant hint found)", which is again correct. Somehow Identify Displays gets different information.

I am running Xubuntu 16.04 LTS "Xenial Xerus" - Release i386 (20160420.1).

The response to `wmctrl -l` is the following: Name: Xfwm4; Class: xfwm4; PID: 1256; Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A.

If I should post anything else then please say.

Screenshot of Settings > Display > Identify Displays

[image]

Comment: Do you have `laptop-mode-tools` installed?  Check with `apt-cache policy laptop-mode-tools` and see if it returned an installed version or "(none)".

Comment: The command `sudo apt-cache policy laptop-mode-tools` returns:   "Installed: (none); Candidate: 1.68-3ubuntu1; Version table: 1.68-3ubuntu1 500; 500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages."

Comment: What's the output from `xrandr`? If you can find the name of the missing display, you can try turning it off with `xrandr --output [display name] --off`

Answer (score 0):

For some (unknown) reason your Benq monitor is identified as secondary display. Check the 'Primary Display' box and do 'Identify Display' command again.

Edit: Set Benq as primary, then select the other (non-existent) monitor and uncheck 'Use this display' option. Then reboot, just to make sure Ubuntu understood everything correctly. This will force Ubuntu to use Benq exclusively. Everything will be peachy as long as you don't use multi-monitors.

Comment: I checked the 'Primary Display' box and repeated the 'Identify Display' command. I also clicked on the BenQ image on that result of the 'Identify Display' command. At some point that got me into a state where the laptop screen (that doesn't exist) had become separated from the BenQ screen and the laptop had (I think) the focus; in other words, I lost all my icons and the mouse and could not do anything. Fortunately right-mouse-click was still available to give me access to commands. Whatever I try, the 'Identify Display' says that I have two screens.